# How to use multiple 'for', 'and' in Shopify Liquid if statement?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I have this css with an 'if' statement:

```
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    {% if section.settings.video_position == 'top' and (section.settings.video_link != nil or section.settings.video != nil) %}
    grid-template-rows: 100px 50vw 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    {% else %}
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    {% endif %}
```

but this syntax throws an error:

> Liquid syntax error (line 404): Expected dotdot but found comparison in "section.settings.video_position == 'top' and (section.settings.video_link != nil or section.settings.video != nil)"

How can I use 'and' with multiple 'ors' in a statement like this?

Comment: you can use conditions like this into liquid code, you need to use 2nd if inside 1st.

Comment: The brackets don't look right. Just wrap the whole code block in the {% if section.settings.video_link != nil or section.settings.video != nil %} first

Answer (score 0):

As @Onkar mentioned in the comments, you will need to use a second if statement inside the first, as Liquid doesn't support brackets inside them.

However, as your problem combines an else statement too, this will mean that you will have to write the else statement twice, one per if statement, like so:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
{% if section.settings.video_position == 'top' %}
  {% if section.settings.video_link != nil or section.settings.video != nil %}
    grid-template-rows: 100px 50vw 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  {% else %}
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
{% endif %}
```

If you want to avoid doing this, you will have to assign a variable for this if statement, and then check that:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
{% assign video_position_top = false %}
{% if section.settings.video_position == 'top' %}
  {% if section.settings.video_link != nil or section.settings.video != nil %}
    {% assign video_position_top = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if video_position_top %}
  grid-template-rows: 100px 50vw 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
{% else %}
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
{% endif %}
```

In your situation, I would use the second suggestion, but assign the required CSS in a variable instead; set a default (what will be in the else statement), and if satisfied, overwrite it:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
{% assign video_position_css = "1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr" %}
{% if section.settings.video_position == 'top' %}
  {% if section.settings.video_link != nil or section.settings.video != nil %}
    {% assign video_position_css = "100px 50vw 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr" %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
grid-template-rows: {{ video_position_css }} ;
```

This is all untested, but it should work.